# A vector that make zero every _continuous_ linear form must be zero

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I am having trouble proving the following result, which I want to do using the most elementary machinery (i.e., no Banach-Hahn theorem or Baire's or other functional analysis stuff).

Suppose $\mathrm{E}$ is a (real) normed space. We say that $\varphi$ is a linear form on $\mathrm{E}$ if it is scalar-valued and linear.

---

Suppose $x$ is a vector in $\mathrm{E}$ obeying the following relation: for every *continuous* lineal functional $\varphi,$ the image of $x$ is zero, that is $\varphi(x) = 0.$ Does it follow necessarily $x = 0$? I do not know any structure in $\mathrm{E}$ except it is normed (proving it for inner-product spaces is easy, we take $\varphi(z) = (x|z)$ "dot product against $x$"). Obviously, one would like to prove that the "projection onto $x$" is a continuous linear form; I explain this further. We assume $x \neq 0$ and extend it to a basis of $\mathrm{E},$ say $\mathrm{B}.$ Then, $$\mathrm{E} = \Bbb R x + \sum_{\substack{y \in \mathrm{B} \\ y \neq x}} \Bbb R y$$
the sum being direct. Every element $z$ in $\mathrm{E}$ can then be written *uniquely* as $\alpha_z x + \sum\limits_{y \in \mathrm{F}} \beta_y y,$ where $\alpha_z \in \Bbb R,$ $\mathrm{F}$ is finite and the $\beta_y$ are *non-zero.* One defines the projection to be $z \mapsto \alpha_z.$ The problem reduces to show that if it is true in general that this projection is continuous.

Comment: It is not going to be continuous in general. For example, $B$ could be chosen such that $B\setminus\{x\}$ spams a dense linear subspace, then you can choose $y_n\to x$, with $y_n\in\operatorname{spam}(B\setminus\{x\})$. Then $x+y_n\to 2x$, but the value of the functional at $x+y_n$ is $1$, while at $2x$ is $1$. That makes it discontinuous. In other words, choosing where the functional is zero, should be done with some care.

Comment: The projection fails then. The result is still true by Banach-Hahn. Any way of proving it without BH?

Comment: Essentially reproducing Hahn-Banach's proof. There is nothing else. If you have shown that for a non-zero vector $v$ there is a continuous functional that is non-zero on it, you have shown that the functional defined on the spam of the vector, returning $\phi(v)\neq0$ can be extended to a continuous one on the whole space.

Comment: Could the general result be equivalent to the Axiom of Choic?